# How to replace array of strings with IDs from another table?

Tags: arrays, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

table 1:

| id | arr |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | ["a","c","b"] |
| 200 | ["d","e","c","a"] |

table 2:

| letter | id |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 3 |
| d | 4 |
| e | 5 |

I need :

| id | id_arr |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | [1,3,2] |
| 200 | [4,5,3,1] |

In Snowflake how to achieve this? I need to preserve order of strings as well. FLATTEN to split array into rows, joining to the other table and back to an array using `array_agg` doesn't preserve order of array elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required step is to use the flatten index column (which is the order of items in the array) as the ORDER BY for the array_agg

```
with table_1(id, arr) as (
    select column1, parse_json(column2) 
    from values
        (100, '["a","c","b"]'),
        (200, '["d","e","c","a"]')
), table_2(letter, id) as (
    select * from values
    ('a', 1),
    ('b', 2),
    ('c', 3),
    ('d', 4),
    ('e', 5)
)
select 
    t1.id
    ,array_agg(t2.id) within group (order by f.index) as id_arr
from table_1 as t1
    ,table(flatten(input=>t1.arr)) as f
join table_2 as t2
    on t2.letter = f.value
group by 1
order by 1;
```

gives:

| ID | ID_ARR |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | [ 1, 3, 2 ] |
| 200 | [ 4, 5, 3, 1 ] |